# Ruby: Define "options" according to function

Tags: ruby

The following function allows me to build a query consisting of a `url` and a number of `options`:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'openssl'
require 'open-uri'

def function(url, options={})
key = '...'
secret = '...'

parameters = {
  :url       => url,
  :param1  => options[:param1],
  :param2  => options[:param2]
}

query = parameters.
  sort_by {|s| s[0].to_s }. 
  select {|s| s[1] }.       
  map {|s| s.map {|v| CGI::escape(v.to_s) }.join('=') }.
  join('&')

secret_key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(url + secret_keyword)

"https://domain.com/action?key=#{access_key}&secret=#{secret}&#{query}"
end

puts function "www.domain.com"
```

In the last line (`puts function "www.domain.com"`) the `url` is defined - but how can I define the `options`?

I tried something like:

```
puts function ("www.domain.com", param1 = "1", param2 = "2")
```

but this is obviously wrong. Please excuse my lack of Ruby knowledge. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Don't put a space before the opening parenthesis

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: removed it, now it says: `can't convert Symbol into Integer` - any idea what could be causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
puts function("www.domain.com", { param1: "1", param2: "2"})
```

Comment: that gives me a syntax error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Comment: removing this space causes two different errors: `unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC` & `unexpected ',', expecting $end`

Comment: By your function definition is like `def function(url, options={})`,  above answer is well enough to pass in it. It looks like some syntax is missing  in your `function` method. Keep trying.